# Get each patients' highest bill

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table where an ID can be associated with more than one bill.  What I need to do is find the `MAX` billing amount, the ID and the date of their highest (`MAX`) bill.  The problem is that there can be thousands of billsper person, and hundreds on any given date.

My query

```
select patientID, max(amountPaid) as maxPaid
from myTable
group by patientID
```

gives me what I need, minus the date.  My attempt at fixing this is

```
select t.patientID, t.maxPaid, myTable.billDate
from myTable
inner join
(
select patientid, max(amountPaid) as maxPaid
from myTable
group by patientID
) as t on t.patientID=myTable.patientID and =t.maxPaid=myTable.maxPaid
```

The error given is `invalid column name maxPaid`.  I tried not giving the calculated field an alias but SQL Server wouldn't accept myTable.max(amountPaid) either.  What's the quickest way to fix this?  thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "fix". What you are trying to do isn't really the best way. While a "quick fix" might be quick, I'm not sure it would be a "fix".

Comment: well, it would be nice to know why this way isn't desirable and then guide me ti a better way.  if i had my druthers :)

Comment: Does you `myTable` have a unique key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that if a patient has two bills with the maximum amount, you will get both of them.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
    patientid,
    amountPaid AS max_paid,
    billDate
FROM
(
    SELECT
        patientid,
        amountPaid,
        billDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patientid
                           ORDER BY amountpaid DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM myTable 
) T1
WHERE T1.RowNumber = 1
```

This will always return one row per patient even if a patient has two bills that both have the same maximum `amountpaid`.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT PatientID, BillDate, AmountPaid,
  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY AmountPaid DESC)
  FROM dbo.myTable
)
SELECT PatientID, BillDate, AmountPaid
FROM x
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on you description, I think you meant this:

```
select t1.patientID, t2.maxPaid, t1.billDate
from myTable t1
inner join
(
    select patientid, max(amountPaid) as maxPaid
    from myTable
    group by patientID
) t2
on t1.patientID=t2.patientID 
and t1.amountPaid=t2.maxPaid
```